# "С Приднепровья" или "Из Приднепровья"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, топонимика

Вопрос элементарный. Можно будет даже стереть после того, как будет отвечен.

Местность возле Днепра — это Приднепровье.
Как правильно писать: ***из*** Приднепровья или ***с*** Приднепровья?

Политики здесь вроде бы никакой нет. Почему-то не могу сам сообразить, как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На выбор предлога в подобных случаях могут влиять различные факторы: семантический (выбор предлога по значению), исторический (традиционность написания) и фонетический (удобство произношения). В данном случае больше подходит форма "из Приднепровья", а форма "с Приднепровья" неудобна для произношения (встреча трех согласных в начале слова). Кроме того,  определение значения сочетания С + ПРИ  может вызывать затруднение.